# Binary subtraction, carry bit not set?

Tags: assembly, binary, flags

I've encountered a situation that seems a bit unintuitive when dealing with binary subtraction and the NZCV flag bits.

Consider the following values

```
0xF7      0b 1111 0111
0xFF      0b 1111 1111
```

If these are both considered to be 8B values where

```
0x000000F7      0b 0000 .... 0000 1111 0111
0x000000FF      0b 0000 .... 0000 1111 1111
```

When subtracted the end result is

```
0x FF FF FF F8    0b 1111 .... 1000
```

I understand how this result is found but I don't understand why the carry bit is not set for this operation.

To my knowledge, the carry bit is set when the MSB is borrowed from, is that not the case here?

Comment: Subtract 0xff is the same as add 0x1. And add 0x1 should not set the carry bit for your example. Btw., which CPU arch is your question about? ARM?

Comment: ARM M0+, is this a 2's complement thing?

Comment: On ARM, the carry bit is inverted for subtractions.  So carry is set if no borrow happened and vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ARM subtraction instructions with carry (SBC, RSC) interpret the carry flag (C) as:

> 0: means borrow
>
> 1: means no borrow

So in your calculation the MSB is borrowed and the carry ist NOT set!

Comment: Yes, and this is the opposite of how x86's CF works.  On x86 it works as the OP was thinking, a non-inverted borrow flag.